# Queue methods in Java?

Tags: java

I am looking to create a pattern in Java that I am not sure how to properly accomplish... right now I have other solutions but I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this sort of pattern

```
        MethodArray methodarray;

        public QueueSimulation(Method method){
            methodarray.add(method);
        }

        public RunSimulation(){
            methodarray.runall(); // runs all the qued methods in order
        }
```

I have many different methods with different names that I would like to queue up.

In other words I have a class for example

Player.Moveup()
Player.Attack()
Player.FallOnGround()
World.LightsOff()

I have many different methods but I want to be able to put all these methods in an array and run them all like the pattern above.

Comment: This looks to me like a single-threaded executor would do. Also, take a look at using the Runnable interface with anonymous classes or java 8 lambdas.

Comment: @Roman maybe you could outline simply as an answer how to use a single-threaded executor to accomplish these 2 methods I am trying to create. Right now it looks like I have to create a seperate class for each method which is sadly not what I wanted but if it is the best way to do this pattern then I must proceed with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something for which you can use a single-threaded [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) with [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)s or [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s which you create as anonymous classes.
A bit of googling led me to the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) factory which helps create a single-threaded executor.

Here is an example:

```
public class MethodQueueSimulator {
    Collection<Callable<Void>> methodQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        MethodQueueSimulator simulator = new MethodQueueSimulator();

        simulator.QueueSimulation(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("1");
                return null;
            }
        });

        // if using java 8+, you can use lambdas instead
        simulator.QueueSimulation(() -> {
            System.out.println("2");
            return null;
        });

        simulator.QueueSimulation(() -> {
            System.out.println("3");
            return null;
        });

        System.out.println("Simulation starts");

        simulator.RunSimulation();

        System.out.println("Simulation complete");
    }

    public void QueueSimulation(Callable<Void> method){
        methodQueue.add(method);
    }

    public void RunSimulation() throws InterruptedException {
        executor.invokeAll(methodQueue);
        // must call shutdown, else process will not exit
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Output when run:

```
Simulation starts
1
2
3
Simulation complete
```

As you can see, the events are executed in sequential order, and the call to invokeAll is blocking, which means that code execution waits for the tasks to complete before continuing, which is why "Simulation complete" is only printed at the end. Of course, this output does not prove the claim, but try it and see for yourself.

Instead of System.out.println, you would invoke your desired methods. I did not know what sort of return values your methods have, so I opted for Void as the return type of the Callables.